# Преимущества cookies в php и javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Добрый вечер.

В чем преимущество установки/чтения cookies у php и javascript?

в каком случае что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это уже зависит от решаемой задачи — для чего используете cookies. По своему предназначению php — серверный, javascript — клиентский. Если вам нужно хранить сессию, чтобы пользователю не приходилось вновь вводить пароль при *подключении к сайту* (обращение к серверу), то тут выбор за php, а если вы используете cookies для временного хранения переменных, которые используете для каких-то вычислений на стороне клиента — javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Ну можно использовать при регистрации например. Чтоб не пришлось сто раз логиниться ставят флажок "Запомнить меня", там я как раз использовал

Answer (score 2):

Нет никакого преимущества, используйте то что нужно.